# How to get attribute values from variable in Python

Tags: python-2.7

So I'm doing a relatively simple project so I can teach myself Python. I've come to a point where I'm stuck. So I have a variable named **element** in pycharm debugger which shows as
[image]

This variable is type Tag, which is correct to me. In **element** I want to see if the `class="schedule_dgrd_time/result"`which is not the case in the above image.

I see that within **element** there is an `attrs`.
[image]

How can I access that value? If I do `element.string` I get the text value which in this case would be **Sat.**(...I could make that work),  but I was wondering if I can check the class attribute value first.

I've been searching for this for a couple days now and just can't get it. I've googled myself to death at this point. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading.

[image]

***Update***
Here is my code

```
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# today's date
date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%-m/%d/%Y')
validDay = "Mon\.|Tue\.|Wed\.|Thu(r)?(s)?\.|Fri\."
website = "http://www.texassports.com/schedule.aspx?path=baseball"

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
##add headers that make it look like I'm a browser
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
page = opener.open(website)
# turn page into html object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
#print soup.prettify()

#get all home games
all_rows = soup.find_all('tr', class_='schedule_home_tr')

# see if any game is today
# entryForToday = [t for t in all_rows if t.findAll('nobr',text=re.compile('.*({}).*'.format(date)))]

# hard coding for testing weekend
entryForToday = [t for t in all_rows if t.findAll('nobr',text=re.compile('3/11/2017'))]

time = "schedule_dgrd_time/result"

for elements in entryForToday:
   for element in elements:
       #this is where I'm stuck. 
        # if element.attrs:
        #     print element.attrs['class'][0]
```

I know a double nested for loop is not ideal so if you have a better way I'm glad to hear it. Thanks

Comment: attrs['class'][0] gives you "schedule_dgrd_game_day_of_week"
is that the question?

Comment: well yes but how do I access it from element? `element.attrs['class'][0]` ?

Comment: Can you please paste the code, or the element Object instead of the print screen?

Comment: Sure, I'll put in main post

Comment: Is your code for parsing HTML ? Something like this: http://effbot.org/zone/element.htm

Comment: Yes it is. I'll take a look at that link to see if I can glean information from that. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Can you please comment if it is working?

Comment: That link is for a different library. My element is just a variable name. I'm not using that library. Unfortunately that won't work for me. Thanks anyway

Comment: How you you create this element Object?

Comment: Can't u use something like this to find the class:
soup.find_all('td', class_='schedule_dgrd_time/result')

Comment: Well there's initially a lot of dates so I look for the one that corresponds to "today"s date. Then I go into to see if the date that it belongs to is during the week. Then if the date is valid, I check to see what the time is on that table row. And that's where I have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure out. I have some NavigableString which doesn't have attrs so that was throwing an error. `element.attrs['class'][0]` does work now. I had to check if isinstanceOf a tag, if not it would skip it. Anywho, my code is below for anyone that is interested.

```
import urllib2
import datetime
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import Tag

# today's date
date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%-m/%d/%Y')
validDay = "Mon\.|Tue\.|Wed\.|Thu(r)?(s)?\.|Fri\."
website = "http://www.texassports.com/schedule.aspx?path=baseball"

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
##add headers that make it look like I'm a browser
opener.addheaders = [('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
page = opener.open(website)
# turn page into html object
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
#print soup.prettify()

#get all home games
all_rows = soup.find_all('tr', class_='schedule_home_tr')

# see if any game is today
# entryForToday = [t for t in all_rows if t.findAll('nobr',text=re.compile('.*({}).*'.format(date)))]

# hard coding for testing weekend
entryForToday = [t for t in all_rows if t.findAll('nobr',text=re.compile('3/14/2017'))]

classForTime = "schedule_dgrd_time/result"
timeOfGame = "none";

if entryForToday:
entryForToday = [t for t in entryForToday if t.findAll('td',
                                                        class_='schedule_dgrd_game_day_of_week',
                                                        text=re.compile('.*({}).*'.format(validDay)))]
if entryForToday:
    for elements in entryForToday:
        for element in elements:

            if isinstance(element, Tag):
                if element.attrs['class'][0] == classForTime:
                    timeOfGame = element.text
                # print element.text
                    break

print timeOfGame
```